# Memory Logging and/or Debugging

Tags: c++, windows

I have built a simple, but rapidly growing, C++ program to assist employees on a Production line. The program is running well on over 80 Clients now, but the newest one is having a problem....

When another program (a generic scanner app) is active, it seems to interfere with mine. My initial assumption is that they are both trying to work with the same .... something? Maybe a file / windows registry / memory block / or even a port. What ever the problem, it is not obvious.
 On occasion the two programs completely lock each other and task manager is needed to kill one (or both) programs.

So my question here:

What can I do? What good (windows 7) system logging could I use? What should I look for?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier checking first what you have changed since the last working version and work on that?

Comment: The problem is only on one PC, and its 'new' (to my program). The other 84 PCs are running fine. Because the PC is new to the Program, I don't have any changes to look at. And because the rest are running OK..... I told them to stop using the other program, and the problem is gone for now, but the other program will be needed again eventually.

Comment: Resource monitor and or process explorer could be helpful identifying handles.

Comment: You also could just create a dump of the process in this broken state via task manager, be sure for it to be a debug version. You can load this dump in vs and examine the threads.

Comment: Add OutputDebugStringA(__FUNCTION__); to any function to tighten the possible fault area. You can see these messages in DbgView

Comment: I was thinking about resource monitor too, but I couldn't find any real info there tho. I'll look into your other suggestions though, hopefully something pops-out :-) The production guys have said they can live without the other program, so I don't need to solve this urgently, but I would like to know. Especially if it is a fault in my code.